# Ubtuntu: Permissions for C program built in Eclispse

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, permissions

I'm building a simple shell as part of an operating systems course for school. I'm building the shell in C using Eclipse on a machine running Ubuntu. I've got it up and running, but the problem is whenever I `cd` to a different directory (i.e. to a directory other than the one where my C program is stored) and try to do anything I get an error that says "Permission Denied".

I'm guessing this has something to do with having insufficient privledges, and I think I could probably fix this by hand-compiling my program using the terminal and involving sudo. I'd like to keep using Eclipse for my debugging and development though so I'm looking for a solution that would work in the Eclipse environment specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Adam, Enter to super-user mode, and cd into the directory that you are not permissioned to go into. sudo requires administrator password.

```
sudo su
cd directory
```